# Publish and show data from rdbms database view to web page, dinamically, changing database view only and F5 on browser

Tags: database, orm, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a general RDBMS database (in particular, SQL SERVER) with multiple views on my tables.

May be these views changes in future, or by field type, or with new field o field renamed.

I would shows these data on a web application;
then, after analysis about future requirements 's customer, i opted to aspnet mvc application based on .net core.

I would use web application just to publish and show data, without any logic that can tightly couple my web app on my data.

In future, i may change database's view (by a field name o field type) and i would web page (view of MVC) doesn't require any change, just F5 pressed.

I found some microsoft magic box (like entity framework core or dynamic data, or also powerbi embedded or lightswitch) that can be helpful for me, but i don't know if it is "dynamic" as i need (change on db, nothing change on code).

Can someone help me?
have you tried same like this?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Data in databases carry semantics (meaning), and at least for any regular application those semantics *MUST* be the same as the semantics (meaning) attached [by the application user] to what is displayed or entered on the screen.  I hope this needs no further explaining and that its consequence is clear that [for any such regular application] you therefore *MUST HAVE* a "coupling" between your "web app and data", even one that is so tight that yet tighter simply doesn't exist.

Another class of software are "technician's toolboxes" that serve no other purpose than to just "view contents" on a technical level, without anything like semantic interpretation or attaching meaning to what is displayed.  Obviously such toolboxes have already been written thousands of times, but if you want to give it a try just for learning that's fine.  But in that case, you should know that you should stay as close to the metal as possible, and not make the mistake of thinking that "microsoft magical boxes" are going to get you anywhere.  Anywhere **closer** to your goal that is.

"As close to the metal as possible" means something like :
- prepare your query
- inspect the query's metadata
- decide your output's structure based upon that metadata
- execute the query
- fill your display

No frameworks involved at all.

Comment: Erwin,
thanks for your first answer.
In the past, i wrote a little bit of logic tu use and decode metadata about field type, length... the scope was to automatically generate TSQL script for tables triggers.

But, after a few years, i think things have changed.
I think same kind o magic box can help us to build a web page based on reversed view's field types.
May be, some dev in the world yet wrote it...
May be, one o that magic boxes ( entity framework core or dynamic data, or also powerbi embedded or lightswitch), used in a particular way, can help us.
What do you think about?
TKS